# Installing Miniconda2 Non-Interactively

Tags: bash, scripting, expect

Is it possible to send multiple responses in sequence to an installation script? Specifically if the install script wants you to press `enter`, then `Q`, then `yes`, like in this post: [install miniconda](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615700/install-miniconda-python-2-7).

I tried piping stuff together, but since I'm pretty unfamiliar with bash scripting, I probably just messed it up or took the wrong approach.

---

**EDIT:**

I tried to write an expect script, but it hangs as shown in the picture below the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ~/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
set timeout -1
expect "$ "
send "\r"
expect "Welcome "
send "Q"
expect "? "
send "yes"
```

[image: expect script]

Comment: First check the tool itself. Usually they'll have flags or config files where you can specify all the choices in advance to do a non-interactive, unattended installation. This is much better than trying to send responses.

Comment: So I looked at the script and saw an flag option `-b` for `run install in batch mode`. What exactly does that mean?

Comment: [I Googled it](https://conda.io/docs/help/silent.html): "Silent installation of Miniconda for Linux and OS X is a simple as specifying the -b and -p arguments of the bash installer. [...] Batch mode assumes that you agree to the license agreement, and it does not edit the .bashrc or .bash_profile files. ." So it will automatically agree to the license, which is exactly what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect):

> Expect is a program that "talks" to other interactive programs according to a script. Following the script, Expect knows what can be expected from a program and what the correct response should be. An interpreted language provides branching and high-level control structures to direct the dialogue. In addition, the user can take control and interact directly when desired, afterward returning control to the script.

---

**Edit:** Looking at the screenshot it's asking you to "press ENTER to continue" which I don't see in your script. You have `send "\r"` but that's not normally what <kbd>Enter</kbd> sends. On Windows it would send `/r/n` and on Linux it sends `/n`. Give that a try.

Comment: Would you mind helping me write the Expect script? I edited the post above to show what I have.

Comment: I've not used expect much myself I'm afraid, I just know that's what it's used for. I'm sure there are a lot of tutorials and examples out there. In general please don't recycle questions, if you have a new issue just post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

This does not require any manual intervention

```html
>curl "https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh" -o miniconda_installer.sh 
>bash miniconda_installer.sh -b -f -p $InstallDirectory
```

Answer (score 2):

For miniconda3, try command line flags instead:

```
bash-4.2# curl -s -L -o miniconda_installer.sh \
          https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

bash-4.2# bash miniconda_installer.sh -h

usage: miniconda_installer.sh [options]

Installs Miniconda3 4.7.10

-b           run install in batch mode (without manual intervention),
             it is expected the license terms are agreed upon
-f           no error if install prefix already exists
-h           print this help message and exit
-p PREFIX    install prefix, defaults to /root/miniconda3, must not contain spaces.
-s           skip running pre/post-link/install scripts
-u           update an existing installation
-t           run package tests after installation (may install conda-build)
```

So the `-b` option could help (might require `-f` and/or `-u` too).